# how to syncState to firebase with re-base?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to persist data with re-base but with this setup, I'm getting nothing. When I try to `addExpense` I'm getting no errors and no new object.

### My re-base setup here:

```
class ExpensesContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expenses: {
        expenseList: []
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    base.syncState(`/`, {
      context: this,
      state: 'expenses.expenseList',
      asArray: true
    });
  }

  addExpense = (expense) => {
    this.setState({
      expenses: this.state.expenses.expenseList.concat([expense]) //updates Firebase and the local state
    });
  }
```

If I'm not using componentDidMount then my addExpense action looks like this and everything works well:

```
  // addExpense = (expense) => {
  //   const expenseList = [...this.state.expenses.expenseList, expense];
  //   this.setState({expenses: {expenseList}});
  // }
```

Comment: Can you show where it is the `.map()` call that fails? Also, where, or how you're using `loadSamples`? And I think it should be `/` in here: `expenses\expenseList`

Comment: please have a look at my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone gets into a similar issue - this the solution that worked for me:

```
class ExpensesContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        expenseList: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    base.syncState(`/expenses`, {
      context: this,
      state: 'expenseList',
      asArray: true
    });
  }

  deleteExpense = (expenseToRemove) => {
    const expenseList = [...this.state.expenseList].filter((expense) => {
      return expenseToRemove !== expense.uid;
    });
    this.props.history.push("/expenses");
    this.setState({expenseList});
  }

  addExpense = (expense) => {
    this.setState({
      expenseList: this.state.expenseList.concat([expense]) 
    });
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expenses: this.state.expenses.expenseList.concat([expense])
```

on the `.setState()` method you're passing the wrong value, that in the end will look like `{ expenses: [<list here>] }` instead should be:

```
expenses: { expenseList: this.state.expenses.expenseList.concat([expense])}
```

and `re-base` doesn't work only with `.concat()` (by reading the documentation I also though the same)

This said, you just need to `.setState()` the expected variable and it should update.

Comment: I trust your answer is helpful but I came up with the solution that I'm  answering to my question